# How to get a direct jump in QSlider without damaging performance

Tags: qt, qtmultimedia, qt-events

I am now creating a simple video player in QT.

I created a slider that is connected with Connect to a multimedia player (he is responsible for running the movie back and forth) and I want it to be moved by a mouse click anywhere on the slide and not just by dragging the cursor.

I tried to do this by adding my own method as follows:

```
class MySlider : public QSlider
{

protected:
  void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
  {
      if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
      {
          if (orientation() == Qt::Horizontal)
          {
              setValue(minimum() + (maximum() - minimum()) * (static_cast<float>(event->x()) / static_cast<float>(width())));
          }
          event->accept();
      }
      QSlider::mousePressEvent(event);
  }

};
```

This is the way I connected the slide to the player:

```
connect(player, &QMediaPlayer::durationChanged,pos_slider, &MySlider::setMaximum );
connect(player, &QMediaPlayer::positionChanged,pos_slider, &MySlider::setValue );

connect(pos_slider, &MySlider::sliderMoved, player, &QMediaPlayer::setPosition);
connect(pos_slider, &MySlider::valueChanged ,player, &QMediaPlayer::setPosition );
```

My problem is that now when the movie is playing, there is lag (the movie hangs for a few seconds every few seconds). In my opinion, because of this addition, I am actually putting a lot more pressure on the player because he has now added events to listen and send.

How can I get the slider moving in a way that will not damage the performance of the player? (Or reduce the performance degradation to a minimum)

thank you
yoko

p.s.

The center of the problem is that I use `connect(player, &QMediaPlayer::positionChanged,pos_slider, &MySlider::setValue );` in the media player and also `connect(pos_slider, &MySlider::valueChanged ,player, &QMediaPlayer::setPosition );` , this duplication is causing performance problems, but I have no idea how I can get rid of this duplication

Comment: The mouse click event probably has nothing to do with it, but the `positionChanged` event could be emitted quite often, as the argument is the position in milliseconds. Still I wouldn't expect a hang for several seconds from the handler alone. Could you try to find out how often the handler is called? Also, did the CPU usage increase when adding this handler?

Comment: Your two handlers might also call each other in a loop with converges only slowly; you could temporarily prevent emitting of events by using [`blockSignals`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#blockSignals)

Comment: @KarstenKoop i know this loop is the problem but what can i do? i need it to update it's location based on video position and also need the video to update his position based on scroller position , i didn't find outher option to do this accept use this loop...

Comment: You can temporarily disable events by using `blockSignals`. Instead of connecting `positionChanged` to the slider's `setValue`, connect it to your own slot, in which you put something like `pos_slider->blockSignals(true); pos_slider->setValue(); pos_slider->blockSignals(false);`

Comment: sound like it will be still very unefficiant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you pointed out yourself, the problem is (probably) due to resonance between `QMediaPlayer::position` and `MySlider::value`.

**Solution 1:**

So, you should avoid changing the `QMediaPlayer::position` when `MySlider::value` is updated programmatically, i.e. do not use the following connection:

```
connect(pos_slider, &MySlider::valueChanged ,player, &QMediaPlayer::setPosition );
```

Instead, you should use the `sliderReleased` and `sliderMoved` signals to update `QMediaPlayer::position` and call `QMediaPlayer::setPosition` manually inside `mousePressEvent` (when appropriate).

**Solution 2:** (thanks too Karsten Koop)

Create your own slot to update the slider value when `QMediaPlayer::position` changed to block emitting signals.

```
connect(player, &QMediaPlayer::positionChanged,pos_slider, &MySlider::updateValueFromMediaPlayer );

void MySlider::updateValueFromMediaPlayer(int pos)
{
    blockSignals(true); 
    setValue(pos); 
    blockSignals(false);
}
```

Note that you do not need the following connection in this case:

```
connect(pos_slider, &MySlider::sliderMoved, player, &QMediaPlayer::setPosition);
```

Comment: Change `setValue();` to `setValue(pos);` :P